# Using Regex for Assert.Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I've ben trying to use Regex to help match two strings using Assert.Matches but i cant seem to get  pattern correct.

```
string text = '012345|Accounts|EffectiveDate|Z1-M1|||2022-03-21|||2022-03-21 18:05:53.566'
var pattern= new Regex($@"(.*?)|Accounts|EffectiveDate|Z1-M1|||(?.*)|||(.*?)");

Assert.Matches(pattern,text);
```

so what i am trying to achieve for the pattern is. the string starts with some digits(not fixed) followed by a specific string then some date followed by some pipelines then followed by some datetime. I'm still trying to learn regex sorry so not sure what im doing wrong here. any help would be appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: You need to escape the pipe symbol (`|`), like `\|` - it has special mening in regex.

Comment: When not escaped, the pipe symbol means: `OR`.

Comment: It should probably be ``Regex(@"^([^|]*)\|Accounts\|EffectiveDate\|Z1-M1\|{3}([^|]*)\|{3}([^|]*)$")``.